# Sum field in sub query in Linq giving Cannot Assign Method error

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I want to be able to group a sub-linq query, but LinqPad is giving an error at this line:

```
ratetocharge =rtc.rate.Sum
```

The error is: Cannot assign method group to anonymous type property.

Could anyone advise what I should enter in that line, to give me a sum of the rate within the rates table?

Thank you,

Mark

```
var mtgRooms = RoomUnit
        .Where(r => r.building_id==1)
        .GroupBy(p => p.Type)
        .Select(g => new
            {
            TypeName = g.Key.type_name,
            TypeID = g.Key.type_id,
            TypeCount = g.Count(),
            rates = rates

        .Select (  rtc => 
                 new  
                 {
                    occ = rtc.occ, 
                    ratetocharge =rtc.rate.Sum  // this is the line which errors
                 }
                   )
                .GroupBy(pe => pe.occ)
             }
            );

            mtgRooms.Dump();
```

**EDIT: To add further detail**

Tables:

**Table RoomUnit**

```
type_id (key - int)
type_name (string - eg. large room, small room, medium room)
building_id (int - denotes a number of buildings this room could be within)
```

**Rates**

```
rate_id
type_id (foreign key to RoomUnit)
occ (type of rate - ie. Desk, FullRoom)
```

The idea is I want to provide a model that looks like this:

```
Type of Room
Number of Types of Room available
Type of Occ/Desks available
Sum of Rate (rate to charge) for each type of desk
```

Currently what shows is:

```
LargeRoom, Type 3049, Type Count 18 (or whatever is available)
    occ FullRoom, ratetocharge 250, numOfOcc 1
    occ FullRoom, ratetocharge 250, numOfOcc 1
    occ FullRoom, ratetocharge 250, numOfOcc 1
    occ Single Desk, ratetocharge 45, numOfOcc 1
    occ Single Desk, ratetocharge 45, numOfOcc 1

SmallRoom, Type 3093, Type Count 4 (or whatever is available)
    occ FullRoom, ratetocharge 150, numOfOcc 1
    occ FullRoom, ratetocharge 150, numOfOcc 1
    occ Single Desk, ratetocharge 45, numOfOcc 1
    occ Single Desk, ratetocharge 45, numOfOcc 1
    occ Single Desk, ratetocharge 45, numOfOcc 1
```

Whereas I would like the model to sum the rateToCharge by Occ in the sub table, eg:

```
LargeRoom, Type 3049, Type Count 18 (or whatever is available)
    occ FullRoom, ratetocharge 750, numOfOcc 3
    occ Single Desk, ratetocharge 90, numOfOcc 2

SmallRoom, Type 3093, Type Count 4 (or whatever is available)
    occ FullRoom, ratetocharge 300, numOfOcc 2
    occ Single Desk, ratetocharge 135, numOfOcc 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `ratetocharge =rtc.rate.Sum` to `ratetocharge =rtc.rate.Sum()`.  Using `Sum` the compiler thinks you are trying to make the ratetocharge variable assigned the method group; the set of methods (including overloads) of the `Sum` method.  Instead you need to make the call `Sum()` which actually calls the method.

--- Edit --- looking at your further information, I am going with this as the way to implement

```
var mtgRooms = RoomUnit
.Where(r => r.building_id==1)
.GroupBy(p => p.Type)
.Select(g => new
    {
    TypeName = g.Key.type_name,
    TypeID = g.Key.type_id,
    TypeCount = g.Count(),
    rates = Rates.Where(rt => rt.type_id == g.type_id).GroupBy(rt => rt.occ)
            .Select(proj => new  {
                occ = proj.Key,
                ratetocharge = proj.Sum(s => s.rate),
                numOfOcc = proj.count())                    
            })              
     }
);
```

Comment: Hi @AlexC - I tried that, but got the error: 'decimal?' does not contain a definition for 'Sum' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Sum(System.Linq.IQueryable<int>)' has some invalid arguments

Instance argument: cannot convert from 'decimal?' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<int>'

Comment: Hi - I've added some more detail to my question, to help show what I'm trying to get at the end.  Currently each sub table is listed individually, I'd like to group it, add the sum of the rate to charge, and a count of how many desks/rooms are included in each.  thank you again, Mark

Comment: Thank you again - the rates.GroupBy(rt => rt.occ) - the rates word is underlined in Linq and it advises: Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Comment: Brilliant - thank you @AlexC - only slight change: == r.type_id to == g.type_id - thank you very much for your time and help, cheers, Mark

Comment: Check out http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b it is very useful